# IF Statement with Number Range on Netsuite PDF/HTML Template

Tags: pdf, if-statement, freemarker, netsuite, bfo

I need to specify default shipping method, for when none is provided on the entry form in Netsuite. For various reasons I have to do this within the PDF/HTML template.
This is the code I have so far, but it doesn't seem to work;

```
<#function toNumber val>
<#if val?has_content && val?length gt 0 >
<#return val?html?replace('[^0-9.]','','r')?number >
<#else><#return 0 ></#if></#function>

<#if record.shipmethod?has_content>

${record.shipmethod}  <!-- if a courier is selected -->

<#else>               <!-- else -->
<#list 2000..2560 as pcx>  <!-- Sydney Metro postcodes -->
<#if toNumber(record.shipzip)==pcx> 

Courier1              <!-- Standard Sydney Metro Courier -->

<#else>               <!-- else -->

Courier2              <!-- Standard Interstate Courier -->

</#if></#list></#if>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is going to print something each time it runs (i.e. 560 lines)! Instead of looping through the numbers, you should to test if the zip code falls within a desired range using the `lte` (less than or equal to) and `gte` (greater than or equal to) [comparison operators](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_comparison):

```
<#function toNumber val>
<#if val?has_content && val?length gt 0 >
<#return val?html?replace('[^0-9.]','','r')?number >
<#else><#return 0 ></#if></#function>

<#assign zip = toNumber(record.shipzip)>

<#if record.shipmethod?has_content>
  ${record.shipmethod}
<#elseif zip gte 2000 && zip lte 2560 >
  Courier 1
<#else>
  Courier 2
</#if>
```